# Responsive flash?

Tags: html, css, flash, background

**EDIT**: I believe its safe to say that Flash is finally being discontinued.

A client recently ask for a flash **background**, ie, the flash had to be on the background.
How do I give a flash object 100% width while the height is defined?

And since the animation will stretch across the screen, is it possible to make the animation repeat itself within the window?

I hope the following image will clarify what I mean -

[image]

(sorry for the half-witted title.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the flashObject at 100% width and a static height in html. Any tiling would have to be done within flash itself. You'd probably have to make heavy use of events that relate to the size of the stage changing.

http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/ would be a good resource to go to as well. It does allow you to use 100% width and specify a max/min height. Unfortunately, the script is no longer in active development, and may have to be modified for modern browsers.

I agree with David's suggestion to go another route, but I know how clients can be sometimes...

Comment: Thanks @Bobrot. I gave 100% width to the flash object and used positioning and z-index to align the flash properly. Then of course, I had to multiple the same animation outside the canvas in Flash. I hope 4000px is wide enough for the flash :P
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This page will help: http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_flashbackground.html

The gist is to give's Flash's `<object>` container CSS properties that define its shape as well as giving it a z-index value so it is positioned behind other page elements (note that you then need to give a z-index to your html's content).

However I must advise you against using Flash in the first place - why can't this animation be done with SVG, Canvas, or HTML5 `<video>`?

I suggest you introduce the Flash `<object>` into the page after doing feature-detection using scripting rather than stick it in the HTML directly, that way users of tablets and smartphones (or just Flash refuseniks) won't see the ugly "plugin needed" box.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)
I tried to persuade him into jQuery related animation.. but all he wanted was 'flash'. Well, completed the job, and the website doesn't look that professional anymore :/